# How to call a function from a template exactly once?

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, rxjs5, angular2-changedetection

I use a function call inside an angular2 template. The function itself performs a http network request using http.get(), and returns an Observable  of any[] that is actually a css style object:

```
@Component({
    selector: "test-component",
    template: `<div *ngFor="let item of items" [ngStyle]="lookupStyle(item)"; }} </div>",
})
@Injectable()
export class TestComponent {

    @Input()
    items: Array<any>; 

    lookupStyle(params: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(/* ... */).map(/* ... */);
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
```

But the above code **will trigger an infinite loop**! The function `lookupStyle` is evaluated every time angular2 change detection takes place. Since `http.get()` will trigger a change-detection run, the function `lookupStyle` is re-evaluated after the http request complete - there is your infinite loop.

Is there a solution or a better way in which i could tell angular to evaluate the function `lookupStyle` only once? Now, I know I could probable come up with some `.zip/.combineLatest` magic on my viewmodel, but this seems overkill and would prodouce a lot of additional code - thats why I am looking for a better way.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from breaking up the `get` method into a separate service file?

Comment: @Scrambo: I put it into the Component to keep the example simple; You will get the same problem if you put the `http.get` into a service file - its the change detection trigger that is the problem (remember, this is not dirty checking as in angular 1)

Comment: Why don't you just make the http calls from ngOnInit(), instead of doing it from the UI?

Comment: Yes, that'll be the .zip/.combineLatest approach I am aware of. Was hoping there is a cleaner solution

Comment: If you use the OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy, you can make change detection run only when you have a new item added to your array.

Comment: @wolfhoundjesse If you phrase that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Dynalon Where you able to fix it. If so how?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want it to run once, then this should do the trick:

```
hasBeenRun: boolean = false;
@Component({
    selector: "test-component",
    template: `<div *ngFor="let item of items" [ngStyle]="lookupStyle(item)"; }} </div>",
})
@Injectable()
export class TestComponent {

    @Input()
        items: Array<any>; 

        lookupStyle(params: any): Observable<any> {
            if(!this.hasBeenRun){
                this.hasBeenRun = true;
                return this.http.get(/* ... */).map(/* ... */);
            }
        }
}
constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

`hasBeenRun` would need to be set back to false elsewhere for if you want it to be called again. Hopefully this is what you were looking for, though I also side with `ngOnInit()` being a very viable solution.

Comment: This is a no-go, as in the template I am using that function in an `*ngFor` environment. your solution would only work for the first iteration, not for all elements. (and btw. everyone can come up with that workaround - but it is not a real solution)

Comment: By avoiding `ngOnInit`, it sort of seems like a workaround is what you're looking for :P